# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mariadb, laravel-8

I have the following syntax error and I can't find the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

**Error**:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`estado` <> ?' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `registros` where Cancelado `estado` <> Terminado)
```

**Query**:

```
$registros = Registro::where('estado', '<>', 'Terminado', 'Cancelado')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Terminado should be 'Terminado'. And which is your column name Cancelado OR estado

Comment: provide your table structure, model etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `whereNotIn` since you cant pass comma separated values to where.

```
$registros = \App\Models\Registro::whereNotIn('estado', ['Terminado' , 'Cancelado'])->get();
```